# Merge 2 columns with priority

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have a pandas df with 2 columns A and B. What I need is a new merged column 'result', in which A is preferred to B. I really thought it would be easy but still no solution. How would you guys do that? Thanks for your help.

```
A   B   result
go  for go
go      go
go      go
    for for
    for for
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.combine_first.html) or [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
df['result'] = df['A'].combine_first(df['B'])
print (df)
     A    B result
0   go  for     go
1   go  NaN     go
2   go  NaN     go
3  NaN  for    for
4  NaN  for    for
```

Or:

```
df['result'] = df['A'].fillna(df['B'])
print (df)
     A    B result
0   go  for     go
1   go  NaN     go
2   go  NaN     go
3  NaN  for    for
4  NaN  for    for
```

EDIT:

For replace empty space to `NaN`s use:

```
df = df.replace('', np.nan)
```

Or:

```
df = df.mask(df == '')
```

Comment: jezrael thank you for your reply. I actually have empty values instead of NaN in the table and couldn't reproduce your solution at first, until I understand that I have to convert all the empty values to NaN to make combine_first work.

Comment: And I just gather enough points to be able to vote answers now, which is soooo cooool!

Comment: You need df = df.replace('', np.nan) or df = df.mask(''). I am on phone only, so untested.

Comment: thats exactly what I did. Thanks jezrael!